# MySql Left Join records where is null with handling validUntil Row

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, isnull

How to select all addons which a specific user has not buyed or are **no longer valid**?
Assuming currentdate is 2017-03-02 17:00:00

Table1 (users):

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | username |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | Walter   |
| 2         | Hank     |
| 3         | John     |
+-----------+----------+
```

Table2 (buyLog):

```
+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| id        | idUsers  | idItems    | validUntil          |
+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
| 1         | 1        | 1          | 2016-03-02 14:15:47 |
| 2         | 1        | 1          | 2018-03-02 14:15:47 |
| 3         | 1        | 2          | 2016-03-02 14:15:47 |
| 4         | 2        | 1          | 2018-03-02 14:15:47 |
+-----------+----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Table3 (addons):

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | Foo      |
| 2         | Bar      |
| 3         | Lorem    |
+-----------+----------+
```

Expected output for user with id 1 should be:

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 2         | Bar      |
| 3         | Lorem    |
+-----------+----------+
```

See SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16356

Where I have the most problems is to handle the validUntil in the leftJoin.
I think I have to group by during the left join to tread only the most recent validUntil record. Maybe using max(validUntil)?

Comment: See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16356/1/0

```
SELECT
C.ID AS 'ID',
C.NAME AS 'NAME'
FROM
(SELECT 
 A.id AS 'ID',A.name AS 'NAME',
 CASE 
 WHEN B.YY > '2017-03-02 17:00:00' THEN 0
 ELSE 1 END AS 'Tag'
 FROM
 addons AS A
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT idItems AS 'XX', MAX(validUntil) AS 'YY' 
  FROM 
  buyLog
  WHERE idUsers = 1 GROUP BY 1) AS B
  ON 
  A.id = B.XX) AS C
  WHERE 
  C.Tag = 1
```

Comment: `Left join c ... where c... =...` is the same as `inner join c`

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that neither your explanation nor your data set and desired result are adequate to the task of explaining the problem. The following query produces the desired result, but perhaps that's just coincidence...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM addons a
  LEFT
  JOIN buylog b
    ON b.iditems = a.id
   AND b.validuntil > NOW()
  LEFT
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = b.idusers 
   AND u.id = 1
  WHERE b.validuntil IS NULL
    AND u.id IS NULL;
```